# A integrable function satisfies some conditions

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a function.

Let $d \geq 1$ and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a open subset.

I am looking for a **unbounded** $L^{p}(U)$ function $f$ (i.e. $\displaystyle \int_{U} |f|^{p}dx <\infty$) satisfies following conditions:

forall $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $E_{\epsilon} \subset U$ (Lebesgue measurable) such that
\begin{align*}
f \notin L^{\infty}(U),\quad \int_{E_{\epsilon}}|f|^{p}dx<\epsilon,\quad |f(x)|\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^{\frac{1}{2}}},\ x \in U \setminus E_{\epsilon}
\end{align*}

Since $f \in L^{p}(U)$, it is easy to check the first condition.

If you know such a $f$, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to pose it another way. In general, for any $f \in L^p(U)$, if $U_M=\{ x \in U : |f(x)| \geq M \}$, then $\lim_{M \to \infty} \int_{U_M} |f|^p dx = 0$. So you are asking for an unbounded function $f$ such that $\int_{U_M} |f|^p dx \leq 1/M^2$ (so you have a specified convergence rate).

So for example, take $U=[0,1]$, $p=1$, $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{-k}}{k}$, and $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n 1_{[a_{n-1},a_n]}$. Then the tail integrals of $f$ are $\sum_{n=N}^\infty 2^{-n}=2^{-N+1}$. You might need to include a constant factor to get exactly your convergence rate, but something like this will do it. The idea is basically the same in $\mathbb{R}^d$: you want $f=n$ on a set of measure $\frac{2^{-n}}{n}$.